# How can I add different types of posts in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

It's a vague question and I've searched throughout the Google and come up short. I want to create a type of content called an `Employee`. He should have 2 pictures attached, some text, a Facebook profile (optional), etc. Can I create a content type to handle this? I've tried the [Custom Post Type UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) Plugin, but that still gives me a standard type of Post, just with a new category, essentially. That's not what I want. I want the Add / Edit post screen to have these options laid out. I can handle the static content just fine with Custom Fields. The hard part is the image uploads.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, very easy to do with a plugin called [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

Comment: Agreed.  My preferred plugin for creating custom content types is Easy Custom Content Types.  You can find it here: http://codecanyon.net/item/easy-custom-content-types-for-wordpress/234182